# Android - How to include a transient field in a serialized object using GSON?

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I'm using GSON with Retrofit to send a JSON object in the request body.
I want to include transient fields in serialization, so I called excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC), but they're still not included in the JSON request body.

```
        // Retrofit Initialization
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation();
        gsonBuilder.excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC);

        retrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder();
        retrofitBuilder.baseUrl(BASE_URL);
        retrofitBuilder.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonBuilder.create()));
        Retrofit retrofit = retrofitBuilder.build();

        // Field to be serialized
        @Expose(deserialize = false, serialize = true)
        @SerializedName("Name")
        private transient String name;
```

Comment: Ummm... The whole point of the `transient` keyword is to inform serializers that the field is *not* to be serialized. "Include transient fields in serialization" is a self-contradictory statement.  If you want the field to be serialized, take out the `transient` modifier.  It won't work otherwise.

Comment: I'm using the transient keyword because I serialize the object and store it in a file too, and I don't want this field to be serialized in this case.
And according to this [guide](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide), the method excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC) should exclude variables with "static" modifier only.

Comment: I stand corrected.  Your code looks like it should work as you expect.  You need to get some visibility into the serialization process.  I looked through Gson to see how you could debug/trace the serialization, but I couldn't find anything.  I suppose you could download the source code and debug that way, but that sounds painful. Apologies for the snarkiness.

Answer (score 0):

Use transient keyword

```
 transient public Drawable icon;
```